# How to convert vectorized transactions into binary matrix transactions

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` called `transactions` with only one field called `items` such that the ith row consists of a vector with the items of the ith transaction, it looks like this:

```
> head(transactions)
                                              items
1                                       Cake, Fudge
2                                       Coffee, Tea
3                                Coffee, Choco, Tea
4                                            Coffee
5                                Bread, Muffin, Jam
6                                            Coffee
```

I would like to convert it into a binary matrix such that each element says if the given object has been bought for the given transaction, it should look like this:

```
   Cake  Fudge  Coffee  Tea  Choco  Bread  Muffin  Jam
1     1      1       0    0      0      0       0    0
2     0      0       1    1      0      0       0    0
3     0      0       1    1      1      0       0    0
4     0      0       1    0      0      0       0    0
5     0      0       0    0      0      1       1    1
6     0      0       1    0      0      0       0    0
```

I cannot find a method to do it without shady nested for-loops. This is all for applying `apriori` from `arules` package, if any of you could lend me a hand on this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [..and other similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20cSplit_e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create new columns for grouping each row (`row`) and the value which we want to represent in case of presence of value which is 1 (`spread_value`). We use `separate_rows` to split every comma-separated value into separate rows. We then `spread` the values from long to wide and in case of absence of value we `fill` it with 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), spread_value = 1) %>%
  separate_rows(items, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(items = trimws(items)) %>%
  spread(items, spread_value, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-row)


#  Bread Cake Choco Coffee Fudge Jam Muffin Tea
#1     0    1     0      0     1   0      0   0
#2     0    0     0      1     0   0      0   1
#3     0    0     1      1     0   0      0   1
#4     0    0     0      1     0   0      0   0
#5     1    0     0      0     0   1      1   0
#6     0    0     0      1     0   0      0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the `cSplit_e` function from [`splitstackshape`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splitstackshape/index.html).

```
df1 <- splitstackshape::cSplit_e(
  data = df,
  split.col = "items",
  sep = ", ",
  mode = "binary",
  fixed = TRUE,
  type = "character",
  fill = 0L,
  drop = TRUE
)

names(df1) <- sub("^items_", "", names(df1))
df1
#  Bread Cake Choco Coffee Fudge Jam Muffin Tea
#1     0    1     0      0     1   0      0   0
#2     0    0     0      1     0   0      0   1
#3     0    0     1      1     0   0      0   1
#4     0    0     0      1     0   0      0   0
#5     1    0     0      0     0   1      1   0
#6     0    0     0      1     0   0      0   0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(items = c("Cake, Fudge", "Coffee, Tea", "Coffee, Choco, Tea", 
"Coffee", "Bread, Muffin, Jam", "Coffee")), .Names = "items", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-dplyr alternative:

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

uniq_words <- df[["items"]] %>% 
  strsplit(", ") %>% 
  unlist() %>%
  unique()

sol <- outer(df[["items"]], uniq_words, str_detect) * 1L
colnames(sol) <- uniq_words

sol
     Cake Fudge Coffee Tea Choco Bread Muffin Jam
[1,]    1     1      0   0     0     0      0   0
[2,]    0     0      1   1     0     0      0   0
[3,]    0     0      1   1     1     0      0   0
[4,]    0     0      1   0     0     0      0   0
[5,]    0     0      0   0     0     1      1   1
[6,]    0     0      1   0     0     0      0   0
```

*data*

```
df <- data.frame(
  items = c(
    "Cake, Fudge", "Coffee, Tea", "Coffee, Choco, Tea", 
    "Coffee", "Bread, Muffin, Jam", "Coffee"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```